# VBA: need help to get started on creating graph(s) depending on userform output in excel

Tags: vba, excel

My idea is to use Userform to create graphs in excel. The userform would have two drop down lists: one is for y-axis and the other one is for x-axis. I want the userform to create a graph with chosen y and x axises in excel.

So far, I know how to make userform with drop down list. I need help to get started to do the rest. I don't know what to do next. Please a link to a tutorial of this similar project or ideas of how to do this would be a great help!

Comment: Try using the macro recorder to learn how to code charts. You will need to add some variables to your chart code for the things you want the userform to change. Then research how to work with userforms and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short guide how to start.

#### Prepare data for charts

For the start I'd suggest to assign names (Define name) to ranges with data and create data validation with exact same names as it was assigned to ranges. (In the code bellow the user chooses x in A1 and y in A2, a list of choices could be: Height, Weight, Age).

#### Create an empty scatterplot chart

```
Sub CreateXYchart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
End Sub
```

#### Update X and Y values with a macro

```
Sub ChangeXY()

    vXCell = "A1"           ' Where the user chooses x
    vYCell = "B1"           ' Where the user chooses y
    vChartName = "Chart 1"  ' Chart name of XY Scatterplot

    vRangeNameForX = ActiveSheet.Range(vXCell).Value
    vRangeNameForY = ActiveSheet.Range(vYCell).Value

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(vChartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(vRangeNameForX)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(vRangeNameForY)

End Sub
```

You could create a button to run a macro. So this is for the start (code assumes that everything is on the same sheet, btw). Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I dont if i got your question try this tutorial , 
[Charting](http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/04/23/interactive-chart-in-excel-tutorial/)

Is a very a good tutorial from a very good website , i recommend for charting and general Excel.
If this isn't what you looking for, tell me !
Good luck !